# Hadith: My tongue is like a scorpion

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> **My tongue is like a scorpion. If I let it loose, it will first bite me.**

What is the origin (if it exists because my Goggle search revealed almost nothing) of this hadith?

Comment: In Arabic there's a word that is used for both scorpion and tongue شبدع : الشِّبْدِعَةُ and there seems to exist a hadith saying whoever bites his شبدع : الشِّبْدِعَةُ will be safe from sins. That's all I could find which is related to hadith.